# Using HTTPOnly Cookie in GET request (Retrieve user info from server using user_id cookie)

Tags: node.js, angular, express, cookies

I'm following a tutorial where, after logging in a user, the backend sends a HTTPOnly cookie to the frontend containing the user id. However, HTTPOnly cookies are not accessible from the frontend (ex. document.cookie will not be able to read the cookie).

My question is, **how is this cookie able to be used to retrieve user data?** My thought process was that you would do something like GET 'server_address'/user/'id' where 'id' would be the user id stored in the cookie. But this obviously cannot work since the frontend can't access the cookie because it's HTTPOnly. A possible workaround I thought of was for the server to send the user id in the JSON response after logging in, but **if this is the solution what is the point of even setting a cookie in the first place?** That workaround makes it seem like there's no point in using cookies at all to save user sessions if you can just send the id back in the JSON response.

Please bear with me, this is my first time working with cookies. If it helps at all, I am using an Angular 4 frontend and a Node/Express backend

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `httponly` cookie is stored in the browser and is automatically resent back to the server with any future requests that match the origin of the cookie.  So, the cookie can be used by the server to identify which client is making the request.  If, for example, it was an authentication cookie that identifies who an authenticated user was, then the server would know which authenticated user this request is coming from and could use that information to authenticate the request and to know which user it was.

As you seem to already know, the httponly cookie cannot be retrieved by browser Javascript.  That is the meaning of httponly.

> how is this cookie able to be used to retrieve user data?

The cookie is sent to the server with any request from that client so the server can use the cookie to identify which user is making the request.

> A possible workaround I thought of was for the server to send the user id in the JSON response after logging in

If the server wants the client to know the userID, then it should return it in the response.  Or, it can stop using an httpOnly cookie so that the client can read the cookie.  But, usually cookies that denote any sort of authenticated state are encrypted on the server so they often aren't intelligible to the client, even if they aren't httpOnly.

> if this is the solution what is the point of even setting a cookie in the first place

Cookies are used for a variety of reasons.  They allow the server to set some state that is associated with that particular client and each future request from that client will send that cookie back to the server so the server can have access to that info.  The info could be authentication info, userID info, user preferences, etc...

> That workaround makes it seem like there's no point in using cookies at all to save user sessions if you can just send the id back in the JSON response.

You don't really tell us much about your application, but cookies are often involved in implementing login and security and because they are automatically sent along with all future requests, they save the client the both of having to attach credentials to every single future request (because the cookie credential are automatically included).  And, for requests such as a user clicking on a link in a page, the cookies are required because those types of links won't have credentials in them (and shouldn't).

> My thought process was that you would do something like GET 'server_address'/user/'id'

So you plan to have any security associate with that request?  If so, then you need an authentication scheme so that not just anyone can request info for any user.  That's often what cookies are used for.  You login, the server sets a credential into an encrypted cookie.  That credential identifies a particular authenticated user so that for future requests from that same client, the server can use that cookie to see who the user is and whether they are authenticated.

Comment: Thank you for that in depth answer hitting every one of my points. Appreciate it!

Comment: Just a quick question, How will the client know if the user has logged in? the cookie is sent by the server and can only be read by the server. How the client app can make decisions based on user has logged in or not?

Comment: @HamzaKhanzada - If the server wants the client to know if it is logged in (which is a reasonable thing), then it can embed that info into the page when rendering the page, either as HTML, as a Javascript variable, a CSS class, etc...

Comment: I am building a SPA, server is stateless and only returns JSON, when the client hit for Login and server returns an httponly cookie, how will the client know at any point that user is still logged in or not?

Comment: So when the login succeeds and server returns me the userid, Should I maintain a cookie separately on client side to know that user has logged in?

Comment: I wouldn't use a second cookie.  I don't fully understand what you're trying to build, but login has to be tested on the server so there has to be a way to communicate that back to the client when the page is loaded which the SPA can then maintain in a state variable.

Answer (score 0):

We set cookie as `httponly` to prevent XSS, imagine if there is a security flaw that allow hacker the inject script `<script>sendToHackerServer(document.cookie)...</script>`, so user's cookie ( include session)  will be sent to hacker server, then hacker can gain access to user data with that session. since these `httponly` cookie will be readable through http request only, session cookie will not be sent by injected script, and ur express backend can read these cookie with `req.cookies`.